# Angularjs + UnitTest BeforeEach Inject not Executing

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write an angularjs spec, but the beforeEach Inject block is not being executed, leaving my test services undefined

```
describe 'VodAssetsTriageController', ->
  $charterModal = null
  controller = null
  FieldService = null
  $q = null
  $rootScope = null
  $scope = null
  VodAssetsService = null
  PidService =
    getPids: _.noop
  AdiSearchService =
    getHeadEnds: _.noop

  beforeEach module('alphonso', ($provide) ->
    $provide.factory 'AdiSearchService',
      $get: -> AdiSearchService
    $provide.factory 'PidService',
      $get: -> PidService
  )


  beforeEach inject ($controller, _VodAssetsService_, _VodAssetsFieldService_,            _$charterModal_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _AdiSearchService_, _PidService_) ->

     controller = $controller
     $charterModal = _$charterModal_
     VodAssetsService = _VodAssetsService_
     FieldService = _VodAssetsFieldService_
     $q = _$q_
     $rootScope = _$rootScope_
     $scope = $rootScope.$new()
     AdiSearchService = _AdiSearchService_
     PidService = _PidService_

     result =
      content: []
     spyOn PidService, 'getPids'
      .and.returnValue $q.when(result)
     spyOn AdiSearchService, 'getHeadEnds'
      .and.returnValue $q.when(result)

     controller = controller 'VodAssetsTriageCtrl',
      VodAssetsService: VodAssetsService,
      VodAssetsFieldService: FieldService,
      $scope: $scope,
      $charterModal: $charterModal

     installPromiseMatchers()

  describe 'controller.paginate.onChange()', ->
    result = null
    searchDeferred = null

    beforeEach ->
      page =
        size: 1000
        totalElements: 179000
      response =
        content: []
        number: 0
        page: page
      result =
       response: response
      searchDeferred = $q.defer()
      spyOn VodAssetsService, 'getAll'
        .and.returnValue searchDeferred.promise
      $scope.searchVm =
        doSearch: () -> controller.search()

    it 'should invoke controller.paginate.onChange() on search() invocation', ->
      controller.search controller
      expect controller.paginate.loading
       .toBeTruthy()

      spyOn controller.paginate, 'onChange'
      promise = searchDeferred.resolve(result)
      $rootScope.$apply()

      expect promise
        .toBeResolvedWith response
      expect vm.paginate.totalElements
        .toBe 179
      expect controller.page
        .toBe result.response.page.number
      expect controller.size
        .toBe result.response.page.size
      expect controller.paginate.loading
        .toBeFalsy()
      expect controller.paginate.onChange
        .toHaveBeenCalled()

    it 'should page to vm.paginate.page = 1', ->
      controller.paginate.page = 1
      controller.paginate.cache[0] = _.range 0, 1000
      spyOn $scope.searchVm, 'doSearch'
      controller.paginate.onChange()

      expect vm.page
        .toBe 1
      expect $scope.searchVm.doSearch
        .not.toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect controller.vodAssets.length
        .toBe vm.paginate.size
```

When I execute the code I am getting the following errors

> Blockquote 
>       Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object in /Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js (line 1815)
>       assertArg@/Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1815:91
>       assertArgFn@/Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1825:12
>       annotate@/Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3810:16
>       $$annotate@/Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2222:41
>       invoke@/Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4501:46
>       /Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4344:85
>       forEach@/Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:340:24
>       createInjector@/Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4344:10
>       workFn@/Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2428:60
>       TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '$q.defer') in /Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/src/app/components/vod-assets-triage/vod-assets-triage.spec.js (line 34)
>       /Users/rbrooks3/sandbox/alphonso-web/src/app/components/vod-assets-triage/vod-assets-triage.spec.js:34:15

Does anyone know why the `beforeEach inject` function is not being called?

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
  beforeEach(module('alphonso', function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('AdiSearchService', {
      $get: function() {
        return AdiSearchService;
      }
    });
    return $provide.factory('PidService', {
      $get: function() {
        return PidService;
      }
    });
  }));
```

module config function shouldn't return anything, and it returns an object.

Also, it obviously should be `$provide.provider` and not `$provide.factory`, short syntax for service mocking is

```
  beforeEach(module('alphonso', function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('AdiSearchService', {
      AdiSearchService: AdiSearchService,
      PidService: PidService
    });
  }));
```